# Unable to add watermark on data table filter

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I was initially using the following to display the watermark on the filter of a dataTable.

```
<p:watermark  forElement=":form:tableId:column3:filter" value="ColumnName3" />
```

It was working with primefaes 3.5

but with primefaces 5 the forElement has been removed and replaced with for. But i now get the error saying that the element with id ':form:tableId:column3:filter' is not found.

My current code looks like

```
<p:watermark  for=":form:tableId:column3:filter" value="ColumnName3" />
```

which does not work.

Comment: Have you checked the id in the resulting html, it might have changed somehow?

Comment: I inspected the id using firebug and put the same

Comment: Post a full example (with the form and table).

Comment: Same problem here: The surounding column complains with an ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this syntax to address the filter field and replace the placeholders with your actual identifiers for the components:

```
<p:watermark for="@(#form\\:tableId\\:column3\\:filter)" value="MyPlaceholder" />
```